# Passing Request Header in Websockets in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, websocket

I am trying to pass additional Request Header in WebSocket connection in Angular for Authorization, but i am not able to find library to achieve that. Is there any way do that ?

I tried using RxJs websocket and Websockets client API.

Comment: You can't. WebSocket protocol is not designed to be like a _normal xhttp request_. What you can do is to pass some custom parameter while connecting: `"ws://yourDomain.com/api/connect?key1=hello&key2=world"`